# Filter unique objects from an ArrayList based on property value of the contained object

Tags: java, arraylist

How will I filter unique object from an arraylist.

```
List<LabelValue> uniqueCityListBasedState = new ArrayList<LabelValue>();
for (LabelValue city : cityListBasedState) {
    if (!uniqueCityListBasedState.contains(city)) {
        uniqueCityListBasedState.add(city);
    }
}
```

This is my code. But the problem is that I need to filter not on the object but on the value of a property inside that object. In this case, I need to exclude the objects that has the name.

That is `city.getName()`

Comment: Consider using HashMap if possible.

Comment: Its not the data structure which is the problem here., imo

Answer (score 6):

```
List<LabelValue> uniqueCityListBasedState = new ArrayList<LabelValue>();
        uniqueCityListBasedState.add(cityListBasedState.get(0));
        for (LabelValue city : cityListBasedState) {
            boolean flag = false;
            for (LabelValue cityUnique : uniqueCityListBasedState) {    
                if (cityUnique.getName().equals(city.getName())) {
                    flag = true;                    
                }
            }
            if(!flag)
                uniqueCityListBasedState.add(city);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can change the list to set.

Use the [Set Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) instead.

> A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `LabelValue` (`hashCode` is not a must in this case):

```
String name;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    LabelValueother = (LabelValue) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve it.

You should override the `equals()` method and `hashCode()` of LabelValue.

And the `equals()` method should use the `name` property and so should the `hashCode()` method.

Then your code will work.

PS. Im assuming that your LabelValue objects can be distinguished with just the name property, which is what you seem to need anyway based on your question.